# canvas.toDataURL is not working with IIS output caching

Tags: javascript, html, iis, cordova, html5-canvas

I have successfully implemented image library PhoneGap app which company users use to view our company published photos. In there I have implemented a feature, when you click an hold on the image then the image will be saved on Camara Roll of the mobile device. For implementing that I used the Phonegap plugin [Canvas2ImagePlugin](https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin)

It was working fine. Recently, I have enabled image caching on the server (IIS 7.5 Output Cashing - added extension .png and .jpg ).

Then suddenly that feature stopped working. Further checking I have found that Canvas2Image plugin uses following method to get the image data from the URL. And after enabling Output caching, **imageData**  is always empty.

```
var imageData = canvas.toDataURL().replace(/data:image\/png;base64,/,'');
```

Can anyone experienced this before? Can you please help me to resolve this?